# Какая книга подробно описывает работу с USB и SD устройствами?

Tags: linux, windows, qt, usb, sd

Меня интересует книга  в которой хорошо описана работа с USB и SD устройствами в Qt, WinApi работа с устройствами. В общем все то, что поможет определить диск устройства, производителя, серийный номер, название устройства и реакцию на удаления из порта и подключение к порту.

Comment: ``man lsusb``  вроде бы

Comment: @misdeed чтоб вытинуть от туда информацию надо устанавливать драйвер Winusb. Я так и не понял как. + мануал мало-понятный

Comment: @misdeed извиняюсь я подумал про libusb мануал.... сейчас буду смотреть

Comment: http://radio-hobby.org/modules/news/article.php?storyid=527

Comment: стоит иметь в виду, что libusb не рассчитан на то чтобы предоставлять инфу о флешке в простой форме... и делать это его средствами сравни ковке собственных гвоздей вместо покупке оных в магазине... здесь скорее стоит смотреть в сторону системных API...

Comment: Под Windows, можно почитать документацию DDK: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/developing-windows-applications-that-communicate-with-a-usb-device